# from A.B import X using __import__?

Tags: python, import

Let's say A is a package directory, B is a module within the directory, and X is a function or variable written in B. How can I import X using the `__import__()` syntax? Using scipy as an example:

What I want:

```
from scipy.constants.constants import yotta
```

What doesn't work:

```
>>> __import__("yotta", fromlist="scipy.constants.constants")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named yotta

>>> __import__("yotta", fromlist=["scipy.constants.constants"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named yotta

>>> __import__("yotta", fromlist=["scipy","constants","constants"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named yotta

>>> __import__("scipy.constants.constants.yotta", fromlist=["scipy.constants.constats"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named yotta
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The python import statement performs two tasks: loading the module and makeing it available in the namespace.

```
import foo.bar.baz
```

will provide the name `foo` in the namespace, not `baz`, so `__import__` will give you `foo`

```
foo = __import__('foo.bar.baz')
```

On the other hand

```
from foo.bar.baz import a, b
```

does not make a module available, but what the import statement needs to perform the assignmaents is baz. this corresponds to

```
_tmp_baz = __import__('foo.bar.baz', fromlist=['a', 'b'])
a = _tmp_baz.a
b = _tmp_baz.b
```

without making the temporary visible, of course.

the `__import__` function does not enforce the presence of `a` and `b`, so when you want `baz` you can just give anything in the fromlist argument to put `__import__` in the "from input" mode.

So the solution is the following. Assuming 'yotta' is given as a string variable, I have used `getattr` for attribute access.

```
yotta = getattr(__import__('scipy.constants.constants', 
                           fromlist=['yotta']), 
                'yotta')
```

Comment: This finally does what I need it to do. I can't say I quite understand why the import statement alone doesn't yell if the fromlist item doesn't exist (ie. replace 'yotta' with 'yyyy'). But, at least you get an AttributeError if 'yyyy' doesn't exist.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
__import__("scipy.constants.constants", fromlist=["yotta"])
```

The argument `fromlist` is equivalent to the *right hand side* of `from LHS import RHS`.

---

[From the docs:](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__)

> `__import__(name[, globals[, locals[, fromlist[, level]]]])`
>
> [...]
>
> The `fromlist` gives the **names of objects** or submodules that should be imported from the **module** given by `name`.
>
> [...]
>
> On the other hand, the statement `from spam.ham import eggs, sausage as saus` results in
>
> ```
> _temp = __import__('spam.ham', globals(), locals(), ['eggs', 'sausage'], -1)
> eggs = _temp.eggs
> saus = _temp.sausage
> ```

(Emphasis mine.)

Comment: Ok ... then I'm confused how any of my code up this point has worked. I've been using the equivalent of:

    dist = __import__('scipy.stats.distributions', fromlist=['scipy','stats'])

because if I leave out the fromlist, dis will simply be 'scipy'.  Does it work both ways then?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I'm not sure how your code there managed to work.

Comment: this still isn't quite right.  if I say yotta = __import__(etc.), yotta is just scipy.constants.constants, and to get the value, you need to do yotta.yotta

Comment: Yes, because `fromlist` can have multiple values in it, it's a list. Thus you still have to assign the items from it into their respective things, as illustrated in the example from the docs.

Comment: `__import__('scipy.stats.distributions')` returns the `scipy` module because that's how the plain import statement works with packages: `import scipy.stats.distributions` puts the root (`scipy`) into the namespace, not the "leaf" (`distributions`); it just makes sure that `scipy.stats.distributions` gets loaded and ready for access. However, if you provide a `fromlist`, then the "leaf" module gets returned from the `__import__()` call. `__import__()` does not really check to make sure that those names exist, so pretty much anything in the `fromlist` will work.